# Error on removing set on migrating from asp to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I am converting a project from asp to aspx.I am just converting the pages from asp to aspx and fixing the errors(as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx) since my client doesn't want me to convert the whole thing.

I have got a file x.asp which is included in login .asp

This is my orginal code(x.asp)

```
function AddX( DX, Parent, Name, Value )    
    Set AddX = AddXEx( DX, Parent, Name, Value, "" )    
End Function

function AddXEx( DX, Parent, Name, Value, Namespace )    
    dim obj    
    set obj = DX.create( 1, LCase(Name), Namespace)    
    if Len(Value) <> 0 then    
        obj.text = Trim(Value)    
    end if    
    Parent.appendChild obj    
    set AddXEx = obj    
End Function  
%>
```

I have removed set and added script language = "vbscript" runat = "server" And this is the code after I made the changes(x.aspx)

```
 function AddX( DX, Parent, Name, Value )              
     AddX = AddXEx( DX, Parent, Name, Value, "" )          
 End Function          

 function AddXEx( DX, Parent, Name, Value, Namespace )          
     dim obj            
     obj = DX.create( 1, LCase(Name), Namespace)          
     if Len(Value) <> 0 then    
         obj.text = Trim(Value)     
     end if     
     Parent.appendChild obj     
     AddXEx = obj     
End Function
```

This is the error I get on compiling

`Compiler Error Message: BC30057: Too many arguments to 'Public Function AddXEx(DX As Object, Parent As Object, Name As Object, Value As Object) As Object'.

Source Error:
AddX = AddXEx( DX, Parent, Name, Value, "" )`

Please tell me how to fix this

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `@page` directive to `Language="VB"` and `Explicit="True"` for ASPX, not `VBScript` and `Option Explicit` as this is for classic ASP:

```
<% @Page Language="VB" Explicit="True" %>
```